# Django StreamingHttpResponse() is causing server to stop working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement StreamingHttpResponse but came across a tedious issue. The connection appears to be established then after around 2 page requests the webserver stops responding. I am truly bewildered about what is causing this issue. If it was associated with an infinite loop, the time.sleep() method should have prevented the server from instantly overloading. I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

views.py:

```
    def event_stream():
    initial_data = ""
    while True:
        data = json.dumps(list(Notification.objects.filter(to_user=1).order_by("-created_date").values("info",
        "return_url",
        "from_user","to_user","created_date")),
        cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

        if not initial_data == data:
            yield "\ndata: {}\n\n".format(data)
            initial_data = data
        time.sleep(1)




class PostStreamView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(event_stream())
        response['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
        return response
```

base.html

```
var eventSource  = new EventSource("{% url 'stream' %}");

eventSource.onopen = function() {
    console.log('We have open connection!');
  }

  eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  eventSource.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(`error ${e}`);
  }
</script>
```

Server Log:

```
2020-10-20 19:25:51 Tue Oct 20 19:25:51 2020 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /AP%20Psychology/ (ip 10.0.0.124) !!!
2020-10-20 19:25:51 Tue Oct 20 19:25:51 2020 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 306] during GET /AP%20Psychology/ (10.0.0.124)
2020-10-20 19:27:33 Tue Oct 20 19:27:33 2020 - SIGPIPE: writing to a closed pipe/socket/fd (probably the client disconnected) on request /post/12/ (ip 10.0.0.124) !!!
2020-10-20 19:27:33 Tue Oct 20 19:27:33 2020 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 306] during GET /post/12/ (10.0.0.124)
```

My hosting provider is PythonAnywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could be going on here. The SIGPIPE errors suggest that either the browser is closing the connection or that the connection is timing out (there's a 5min limit on open connections on PythonAnywhere) When a connection is open for more than 5 minutes, your web app may be restarted, so having some code the break the connection and rebuild it before the 5 min limit, would prevent that. Another possibility is that you're running out of workers. Each stream will tie up a worker for however long it is help open and you'll need at least one worker to handle ordinary requests.

Comment: Got it, my program is going to be made with the assumption that thousands of users will be on it. Is it unrealistic to assume that I will be able to use this method for real-time updates?